# Publish JAXWS Endpoint in the same port than Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services

I am having issues with the implementation of JAXWS for expose the endpoint that will consume the soap message in the same port that API rest or default spring boot port.

I am using this :

Plugin for generated code from wsdl : org.codehaus.mojo>jaxws-maven-plugin-2.6

Java 11 + Spring boot 2.7.13 + jakarta.xml.ws-api-4.0.1

```
package net.gencat.salut.sivec.external.cases.config;

import jakarta.xml.ws.Endpoint;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import net.gencat.salut.sivec.external.cases.argo.CarregaImpl;
import net.gencat.salut.sivec.external.cases.notification.NotificationSoapImpl;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class WebServiceConfig {


 @Bean
  public CarregaImpl carregaImpl() {        
    return new CarregaImpl();
    
 }


 @Bean
 public Endpoint publishEndpoint(final SoapProperties soapProperties,CarregaImpl carregaImpl) 
  {
    log.info("Endpoint argo published: {}",soapProperties.getUri());
    return Endpoint.publish(soapProperties.getUri(), carregaImpl);
    
  }


}
```

The value of getURi is this: http://localhost:8989/ws/

This is my log:

[image]

Solution 1 what I want

I want to know how i can to configure JAXWS Endpoint for use the same port than Spring boot if with the solution or implementation what I did , I can't use the same port because spring boot shows in runtime "port in use"

[image]

Solution 2: If I configure two different ports, how I have configured the endpoint to http://localhost:8989 when I deploy this microservice in Openshift and see all the port on listen

For the port 8989,  it shows "localhost:8989" instead of ":::8989" what is how is shown the default spring boot port, then I have a redirect issue because unable to resolve localhost:8989 in cloud

Someone can help me?. Please any recomendation is welcome but one example would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have an app running both rest and SOAP server on the same port. I'm using a different plugin though:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static</source>
                    </sources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

in my static folder, I have my xsd files.

After that, my configuration class is a bit different:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
class WebServiceConfig : WsConfigurerAdapter() {

    // Global URL registration
    @Bean
    fun messageDispatcherServlet(applicationContext: ApplicationContext): ServletRegistrationBean<MessageDispatcherServlet> {
        val servlet = MessageDispatcherServlet()
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext)
        servlet.isTransformWsdlLocations = true
        return ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/webservices/*", "/ws/*")
    }

    @Bean
    fun schema1(): XsdSchema {
        return SimpleXsdSchema(ClassPathResource("static/schema1.xsd"))
    }

    @Bean(name = ["Schema1Service"])
    fun schema1Definition(accountBalancerSchema: XsdSchema): Wsdl11Definition {
        val wsdl11Definition = NoRequestSuffixWsdl11Definition()
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("Schema1Definition")
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/webservices")
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace(Schema1Endpoint.NAMESPACE_URI)
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(schema1)
        return wsdl11Definition
    }

    // ... with new beans for each xsd
}
```

This is Kotlin code but the concept is the same in Java.

Then, the endpoint looks like:

```
@Endpoint
class Schema1Endpoint(
// All autowired necessary
) {
    companion object {
        const val NAMESPACE_URI = "https://whatever.your.namespace.is"
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "matching def from xsd")
    @ResponsePayload
    fun function1(@RequestPayload request: Function1Request): Function1Response { // Request & Response are auto generated
        // do what you need to here
        val response = Function1Response()
        // set what you need on the response
        return response
    }

    // All other functions...
}
```

I hope this helps.

UPDATE1:
Adding the NoRequestSuffixWsdl11Definition:

```
package no.schibsted.dib.online.config.utils

import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.ProviderBasedWsdl4jDefinition
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.Wsdl11Definition
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.SoapProvider
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.SuffixBasedMessagesProvider
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.SuffixBasedPortTypesProvider
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema
import javax.xml.transform.Source

class NoRequestSuffixWsdl11Definition : Wsdl11Definition, InitializingBean {
    private val typesProvider = InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider()

    private val messagesProvider: SuffixBasedMessagesProvider = NoRequestSuffixBasedMessagesProvider()

    private val portTypesProvider: SuffixBasedPortTypesProvider = NoRequestSuffixBasedPortTypesProvider()

    private val soapProvider = SoapProvider()

    private val delegate = ProviderBasedWsdl4jDefinition()

    init {
        delegate.typesProvider = typesProvider
        delegate.messagesProvider = messagesProvider
        delegate.portTypesProvider = portTypesProvider
        delegate.bindingsProvider = soapProvider
        delegate.servicesProvider = soapProvider
    }

    fun setTargetNamespace(targetNamespace: String?) {
        delegate.targetNamespace = targetNamespace
    }

    fun setSchema(schema: XsdSchema?) {
        typesProvider.setSchema(schema)
    }

    fun setPortTypeName(portTypeName: String?) {
        portTypesProvider.portTypeName = portTypeName
    }

    fun setLocationUri(locationUri: String?) {
        soapProvider.setLocationUri(locationUri)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun afterPropertiesSet() {
        if (!StringUtils.hasText(delegate.targetNamespace) && typesProvider.schemaCollection != null && typesProvider.schemaCollection.xsdSchemas.size > 0) {
            val schema = typesProvider.schemaCollection.xsdSchemas[0]
            setTargetNamespace(schema.targetNamespace)
        }
        if (StringUtils.hasText(portTypesProvider.portTypeName)) {
            soapProvider.setServiceName(portTypesProvider.portTypeName + "Service")
        }
        delegate.afterPropertiesSet()
    }

    override fun getSource(): Source? {
        return delegate.source
    }
}
```

Comment: The first days, I tried that solution using spring boot webservices but it didn't work me  .as you know Spring boot not generate fine the wsdl due to the suffix, the elements of my schema don't have the suffix request or response. How have you implemented the NoRequestSuffixWsdl11Definition method? For this reason I am using JAXWS

Comment: I added my `NoRequestSuffixWsdl11Definition`